docker run results in "no such file or directory" for any executable on Bazel-built oci_image
Currently working on building some OCI images with Bazel through rules_oci and rules_distroless. I have the following build file loosely extracted from the official rules_distroless example ubuntu_snapshot:
oci_image(
    name = "foo",
    architecture = select({
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64": "arm64",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": "amd64",
    }),
    os = "linux",
    tars = [
        "//os/ubuntu_noble:sh",
        "//os/ubuntu_noble:passwd",
        "//os/ubuntu_noble:group",
        "//foo:foo_dpkg_status",
    ] + select({
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64": [
            "@noble//ncurses-base/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//libncurses6/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//tzdata/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//bash/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//coreutils/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//dpkg/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//apt/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//perl/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//qbittorrent-nox/arm64:arm64",
        ],
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": [
            "@noble//ncurses-base/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//libncurses6/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//tzdata/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//bash/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//coreutils/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//dpkg/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//apt/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//perl/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//qbittorrent-nox/amd64:amd64",
        ],
    }),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

Then there's a simple oci_load rule
oci_load(
  name = "tarball",
  image = "//foo:foo",
  repo_tags = ["local/foo:latest"],
)

Trying to run:
docker run --rm -it local/foo:latest /usr/bin/bash

Results in:
exec /usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory

In fact, that happens for any executable inside the image. An interesting thing is that if I try to run an executable that truly does not exist in the image, I get a slightly different error:
docker run --rm -it local/foo:latest /bin/garbage
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/garbage": stat /bin/garbage: no such file or directory: unknown.

What can I do to further debug the issue? Also what might be the issue? Am I missing something obvious?
What I tried
I tried figuring out whether the binaries actually make it into the image, so I exported the filesystem of the container:
export CID=$(docker create local/foo:latest /bin/bash)
docker export $CID -o rootfs.tar.gz

Now examining the tarball actually shows plenty of executable files on the system, e.g. bash:
tar -tvf ./rootfs.tar.gz | grep usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0     1543048 22 Feb  2024 usr/bin/bash

Another thing I tried is removing the @noble//qbittorrent-nox OR placing it at the beginning of the package list in the select(...). In both cases, it all works out fine. Seems like it's this package that's breaking the whole thing, but I am not sure I understand why.
Other StackOverflow questions

binary file not found when running bazel oci_image on local docker

Full Example
A full example to reproduce the issue can be found and built at https://github.com/barbu110/bazel-oci-image-issue.

Can you run the extracted binaries? If they aren't statically linked, make sure all of the libraries are also in the export (ldd usr/bin/bash). Is the binary for your local architecture or are you trying to run a different platform?

The host is macOS arm with docker desktop installed. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

@BMitch tried running another container with ubuntu:noble with the tarball mounted as a volume and I can confirm I can execute the binaries in the tarball.

Also, it turns out that if I move @noble//qbittorrent-nox to be the first select list, bash can be executed through docker run... I don't get this

You may want to call out that this is a Bazel question in the title. A majority of people looking at the docker tag don't build their images using that.

@BMitch makes sense, thanks!

Let’s isolate qbittorrent-nox into a separate target and add it as a dependency, instead of including it directly in the main image tarball. This will allow Bazel to manage it separately, reducing conflicts with other layers.
Update your BUILD file accordingly:
    # Define `qbittorrent-nox` as a separate target to isolate its layer
oci_image(
    name = "qbittorrent_nox_image",
    architecture = select({
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64": "arm64",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": "amd64",
    }),
    os = "linux",
    tars = select({
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64": [
            "@noble//qbittorrent-nox/arm64:arm64",
        ],
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": [
            "@noble//qbittorrent-nox/amd64:amd64",
        ],
    }),
)

# Main OCI image
oci_image(
    name = "foo",
    architecture = select({
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64": "arm64",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": "amd64",
    }),
    os = "linux",
    tars = [
        "//os/ubuntu_noble:sh",
        "//os/ubuntu_noble:passwd",
        "//os/ubuntu_noble:group",
        "//foo:foo_dpkg_status",
    ] + select({
        "@platforms//cpu:arm64": [
            "@noble//ncurses-base/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//libncurses6/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//tzdata/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//bash/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//coreutils/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//dpkg/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//apt/arm64:arm64",
            "@noble//perl/arm64:arm64",
        ],
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": [
            "@noble//ncurses-base/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//libncurses6/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//tzdata/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//bash/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//coreutils/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//dpkg/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//apt/amd64:amd64",
            "@noble//perl/amd64:amd64",
        ],
    }),
    base = "//:qbittorrent_nox_image",  # Add qbittorrent_nox as a base
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

Verify Debug Layer Paths and File Existence
After building the image, export the image filesystem.
export CID=$(docker create local/foo:latest /usr/bin/bash)
docker export $CID -o rootfs.tar.gz

Verify bash’s accessibility in rootfs.tar.gz
tar -tvf rootfs.tar.gz | grep usr/bin/bash

Ensure qbittorrent-nox and bash dependencies are layered and accessible.
Try a Debug Image Variant
Switch to a debug variant of the distroless image for more debugging tools.
oci_image(
    name = "foo_debug",
    base = "@distroless//debug",  # Temporary debug base
    ...
)

Now, run the container with a shell:
docker run --rm -it local/foo_debug:latest /bin/sh

This lets you inspect the environment, paths, and confirm /usr/bin/bash and other binaries are present.
Run Docker with a Simpler Shell
To isolate bash, try running with a simpler shell like sh.
docker run --rm -it local/foo:latest /bin/sh

If this works, there might be additional bash-specific dependencies missing.
